# Can .NET assemblies be placed in the application folder instead of the GAC?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac

Is it OK to have .NET DLLs in the App folder instead of the GAC?  Will the application still work if they are put in the App folder?

Comment: Is this *your* application, or one that you're trying to run? If it's your own application, I highly suggest keeping your DLLs in the local application folder, rather than placing them in the GAC. That adds another level of complexity, for what I feel is very little benefit in the overwhelming majority of cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**—in general, the application should still work if the DLLs are in the same directory as the application (EXE).

Answer (score 1):

I rarely put stuff in the GAC. I do most of the times put all DLLs in the application folder.

Beware that .Net tries to find a DLL in the GAC before in the application folder. This means that you app will not use the version in your app folder if a newer version of the DLL exists in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

Mark is right, but keep in mind that there are important differences, one of them being that GAC'ed DLL's are fully trusted.

Comment: DLL's in the app folder is fully trusted too, since the user put them there ;) Seriously: If the app is signed, all DLL's have to be signed too. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jgauffin: Yes, it's a bit more complicated than that. A DLL in an app folder has the rights it would have from that directory, which isn't always the same as full trust.